# What is mean JSON file generate by Azcopy

Tags: azcopy

When I using Azcopy v7.3 to copy Table Storage. I receive 2 files JSON and manifest. Name of JSON file will be generated with the format `myfilename_XXXXXXX`.When I rename JSON file Azcopy throw exception. I really want to know how to `XXXXXXX` will be generated and how can file JSON file map with the manifest file.
Thanks for your help [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suffix is the `CRC64` calculated by the entities content in this JSON file, and the manifest file stores the total `CRC64` aggregated by all the JSON files. This is to ensure that file list is complete and each JSON file isn't corrupted respectively.